# Loading source controlled MonoDevelop project leaves out some folders

Tags: c#, unity, mono

I have recently started using version control in MonoDevelop and have discovered that if I include a folder containing for example Scenes that they will be included when I push changes to master.

My structure is:

Scripts

--> Armour.cs

--> Inventory.cs

Scenes

--> Scene01.unity

However when I reopen the unity project and look at the code solution only the Script directory and the files within it appear and the Scenes folder is absent.

Strangely enough Scene01.unity is still getting picked up if I make a change and go to commit changes.

This is what I want my project to [look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R9TB.jpg)

Does anyone know why this is happens and if there is any way to resolve this?

NOTE: As a basic work around I can manually include the file when it disappears however when I have a large amount of assets this could become a painful task. Also if I load the project using MonoDevelop it loads fine, but opening from Unity itself seems to overwrite the solution files.

Comment: What SCM are you using, specifically? Git?

Comment: @Grey Yes I am using Git

Comment: I don't think its anything to do with Git itself, I fairly certain that the issue is with Unity making changes to the solution when it loads from the unity interface. If I check the diff of the solution I can see it actually drops the folders I have added with non-code related assets.

Comment: To my knowledge, Unity is actually managing the MonoDevelop solution file, and it will only include the actual scripts (as well as text and XML files, in case they are available), but none of the other assets.

Comment: @xeophin that sounds like what is happening, do you know of any way this can be disabled or changed so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no problem with your tools.

Git is saving the changes and your repository is working as expected, according to what you're saying. On the other hand, MonoDevelop is a tool for code editing, and the Unity editor is the tool for managing assets and the whole project.

This is an example project and, as you can see, in both MonoDevelop and Visual Studio, the solution loads the scripts only; because that's the idea.

**Unity Project window**

[image: Unity Project window]

**MonoDevelop Solution panel**

[image: MonoDevelop Solution panel]

**Visual Studio Solution panel**

[image: Visual Studio Solution panel]